# What's the proper way of calling COM enumerators in .NET?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, com-interop

I am calling an externally provided COM DLL for which I have generated a COM interop wrapper. For the sake of argument, let's call the interface I want to call `IEnumFoo`.

`IEnumFoo` has the typical COM enumerator pattern:

```cpp
HRESULT Next ( 
   ULONG        celt,
   IFoo**       rgelt,
   ULONG*       pceltFetched
);
```

where the first parameter is the number of desired results, the second parameter is a buffer to which results are written, and the last parameter describes the number of results actually written.

When I choose "Add Reference" and point Visual Studio at this DLL, it generates a COM Interop Assembly with the following signature:

```c#
void Next(uint, out IFoo, out uint)
```

This only allows the .NET code to request a single object at a time, which can add a significant amount of overhead to using these APIs.

Is there some mechanism I can use to generate a version of `Next` which would allow me to provide more `IFoo` "slots" above which would make the marshaler happy? (I'm not averse to editing the IL in the interop assembly by hand :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper signature for this would be like so:

```
void Next(
    uint celt,
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0)] IFoo[] rgelt,
    out uint pceltFetched);
```

According to MSDN, at least, there's no mechanism to generate this automatically. Even if the original IDL for the interface had `length_is` applied to `rgelt`, that information is lost in the typelib. So you'll need to edit the interop assembly manually.

One other option is to define this particular interface entirely by hand in your main assembly, and simply ignore the generated interop version. Remember that when doing casts on RCWs, any interface with a matching GUID (i.e. the one for which QueryInterface is successful) will work, so you can actually have several different managed interfaces that present differing views of the same COM interface.

Comment: I would definitely go for editing the IL as redefining one interface amongst many in a typelib can be a daunting task because of the cross references "snowball effect". You may end up redefining the whole library. Note a tool such as mono cecil (http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) is very useful for tweaking a compiled assembly.

Comment: Looks like that'll work :) (Same comment about the "Remember:" though -- that assumes I know what I'm doing :P)

Answer (score 2):

Not answer to your question but a suggestion to try a different approach. I'd create a C++/CLI wrapper to enumerate through the COM interface in unmanaged code (thus avoiding the marshaling overhead) and then build a managed `List` or other container in which you return your objects.

This is almost guaranteed to be easier than hand-tweaking the IL of the interop assembly and you can debug it easily, too. The unmanaged C++ code will be fairly simple, just like the managed wrapper around that.

Comment: Writing a shim around this library in C++/CLI is infeasible at this time. (Though it is something to consider in the future)

Comment: @BillyONeal You don't have to do it for the entire library - you can write it just for the enumerators. You'd only need to pass the object instance, the enumerator and then the wrapper would return a managed list. For all other tasks you can still use the generated interop assembly.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting (+1). Still want to look for a solution that avoids C++/CLI but that's an option. (Need to figure out how to create a .NET COM RCW from C++/CLI :) if I go that route too)

Answer (score 1):

If the object implementing this interface is native, then just redefine the interface in your code as it should be, making sure to use the same ComImport and Guid attributes on the interface. Then take the object and cast to your interface. You can call through that interface just fine.

Remember: interop assemblies aren't magic, you can always define an interface manually.

Comment: That "Remember:" clause assumes the reader has any real understanding of how the interop works. Which this poster does not :) Thanks!

Comment: Or it can be the basis of new understanding. ;-)